# LuaLaTeX string literal - keep the new lines in a latex macro

Tags: luatex

In LuaLaTeX, what I gather is if your Lua string has `\n`, you can print your string line by line and the code will be reproduced faithfully. But if you set that string to a macro, it will not work. See below.

```
\begin{luacode*}
    multilines = [[
    hello

    world
    ]]

    for line in multilines:gmatch"[^\n]*" do -- works fine
        tex.print(line)
    end

    token.set_macro('multilines',multilines,'global') 

\end{luacode*}

    \multilines % does not satisfy
```

One little hack I came up was to do this: `multilines:gsub('\n\n','\\par ')`.
But I have a new issue. let's say I want to assign the following text (in Lua), to a LaTeX macro:

```
md = [[
        \begin{markdown}
        # section name

        - list1
        - list2
        \end{markdown}
        ]]

        --token.set_macro('md',md,'global') -- doesnt work
        token.set_macro('md',md:gsub('\n\n','\\par '),'global') -- doesnt work
```

How to keep the new lines of the `md` string literal when pushing them to a LaTeX macro?

Comment: please always post code in the form of a test document that can be run to see the issue. if you keep a single newline in a lua string and write it to tex then that will act like a newline in a source file and produce a normal inter-word space. Is that what you areasking for or do you want to write a paragraph break (blank line) or newline `\\ ` into the tex stream?

Comment: also do you have to use the luacode package which complicates things here?  It is simpler if your lua code is in a lua file `yourfile.lua`  that you access as `\directlua{require('yourfile')}`

Comment: you have not provided an example or defined `markdown` but if that is a verbatim-like environment (presumably is if you can use `#`) then the issue will be the usual one that you can not use verbatim in the argument of another macro. It may be simplest to write the string to a file then read it back with the expected catcodes